# Find two 2 permutations of the numbers of set $\{\frac 11,\frac 12,\dots,\frac 1n\}$ with certain properties.

Tags: number-theory

The problem is: Let $n>1$ be a natural numbers, $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ and $(b_1,b_2,…,b_n)$ are $2$ permutations of the numbers in set $\{\frac 11,\frac 12,\dots,\frac 1n\}$, satisfying $a_i+b_i\ge a_j+b_j$ for all $i<j$. Does there exist $2$ permutations in which $a_i$ is not equal to $b_i$ for all $i$ and $\frac{a_1+b_1}{a_n+b_n}$ is an integer? I try for small $n$ like $3$ or $4$ and it seems to be there is no such permutation to satisfy. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Hi tmt. We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what you're trying to ask.  Please put the entire question in the question (not the title) and use MathJax to typeset your question.  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertShore You might be referring to the question body. Indeed, please put the question in the question body. The title should be used to describe the question, not the question itself if necessary.

Comment: I’m new to this site and Latex so I don’t know how to use MathJax as well. You can look for the problem in the description underneath and I’m truly sorry for this

Comment: It's easy to learn MathJax.  Follow the link in the first comment.

Comment: I am going to fix your typing, if you agree with that meaning, could you help me to approve it?

Comment: I would love to have you fix my typing

Answer (score 2):

Consider the counterexample:
\begin{align}
(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{12}) &= \bigg(\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{1}{9}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{10}, \frac{1}{7}, \frac{1}{11}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{12} \bigg) \\
(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_{12}) &= \bigg(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{9}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{1}{10}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{11}, \frac{1}{7}, \frac{1}{12}, \frac{1}{8} \bigg)
\end{align}

It is easy to see that $a_i+b_i \geqslant a_j+b_j$ for all $i<j$. Moreover:
$$\frac{a_1+b_1}{a_n+b_n} = \frac{\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{12}} = \frac{\frac{5}{4}}{\frac{5}{24}} = 6$$

---

So what's the intuition behind this construction? We want to make sure that the numerator of $a_n+b_n$ is as small as possible to maximize our chance of getting $\frac{a_1+b_1}{a_n+b_n}$ to be an integer. Assuming one of $a_n$  and $b_n$ is $\frac{1}{n}$, we could try making the other as $\frac{1}{n/2}$. However, this will interfere with our condition that $a_i+b_i \geqslant a_j+b_j$ for all $i < j$ (I'll let you figure out why!). Thus, we could instead try keeping $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{2n/3}$. Then:
$$a_n+b_n = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{2n/3} = \frac{5}{2n}$$
Now, we need to make sure that $5$ divides the numerator of $a_1+b_1$. It is easy to see that one of $a_1$ and $b_1$ must be $1$, so we can try taking the other as $\frac{1}{4}$. Then, we have:
$$\frac{a_1+b_1}{a_n+b_n} = \frac{\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{2n/3}+\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{\frac{5}{4}}{\frac{5}{2n}} = \frac{n}{2}$$

We need to make sure that $\frac{n}{2}$ and $\frac{2n}{3}$ are integers, so $6 \mid n$. This strategy won't work for $n=6$ because $\frac{2n}{3} = 4$. For $n=12$, we can use the pairing trick done in the counterexample provided above to achieve the required.